# Cancancan gem while using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, cancancan

I have problem with my feature test for users creating new content. It passes only when I comment or delete this line in my controller. It looks like factory :user doesn't have ability to create new content. I checked factory using seperate test to check if it has ability to create new word and it has. What can be problem here?

```
authorize! :create, @word, :message => "Musisz się zalogować, aby dodać nowe słówko."
```

words_controller.rb

```
def create
    authorize! :create, @word, :message => "Musisz się zalogować, aby dodać nowe słówko."
    @user = current_user
    @word = @user.words.build(word_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @word.save
        format.html { 
          redirect_to new_word_path
          flash[:notice] = 'Słówko zostało prawidłowo zapisane. Dodaj następne!'
        }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @word }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @word.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

user_creates_word_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'User creates word' do


  before(:all) do

    category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)

    10.times { word = FactoryGirl.create(:word) }

    sign_in
    expect(page).to have_content 'Wyloguj się'
    visit game_words_path
    click_link('Dodaj słówko')
  end

  scenario 'with valid input' do
    fill_in 'Angielski', with: 'house'
    fill_in 'Polski', with: 'dom'
    find(:css, ".check_boxes[value='1']").set(true)
    click_button 'Zapisz'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Słówko zostało prawidłowo zapisane.'
  end

end
```

test to check if user factory has ability to create new word

```
it "can create new word" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  ability = Ability.new(user)
  word = Word.new(user: user)
  expect { ability.should be_able_to(:create, word)}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed this lines:

```
authorize! :create, @word, :message => "Musisz się zalogować, aby dodać nowe słówko."
@user = current_user
@word = @user.words.build(word_params)
```

to:

```
@user = current_user
@word = @user.words.build(word_params)
authorize! :create, @word, :message => "Musisz się zalogować, aby dodać nowe słówko."
```

And it works fine. In the previous version variable @word was definied after authorize! method, so it doesn't work properly.